# Make Elemenst active on navbar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

This is my sidebar page code

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="<?php echo Config::get('url'); ?>dashboard.php" class="element active"><i class="lnr lnr-home"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Config::get('url');?>company.php" class="element"><i class="lnr lnr-chart-bars"></i> <span>Company Detail</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Config::get('url'); ?>address.php" class="element"><i class="lnr lnr-chart-bars"></i> <span>Address Book</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Config::get('url'); ?>product.php" class="element"><i class="lnr lnr-cog"></i> <span>Products</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Config::get('url'); ?>bill.php" class="element><i class="lnr lnr-alarm"></i> <span>Invoice</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

When user clicks on company link i want the company to have active class, so to do that i have this script code :

```
  <script>
    var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
    console.log(btns);
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
    });
    }
     </script>
```

So, when the company page loads it resets the active class back to dashboard.

How can i apply active class to elements of sidebar?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check current url and url in a navbar item. It they are the same add class, in __php__.

Comment: That would work but is there any other way to work around this?

Comment: If you do not want to check with URL, you can add active page variable in start each of this files and check value of this variable in your menu

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul class="nav">
 <li>
     <a href="<?php echo Config::get('url'); ?>dashboard.php" class="element<?='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == (Config::get('url') . 'dashboard.php') ? ' active' : ''?>">
         <i class="lnr lnr-home"></i> 
         <span>Dashboard</span>
     </a>
 </li>
 <li>
     <a href="<?php echo Config::get('url');?>company.php" class="element<?='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == (Config::get('url') . 'dashboard.php') ? ' active' : ''?>">
         <i class="lnr lnr-chart-bars"></i>
         <span>Company Detail</span>
     </a>
 </li>
 <li>
     <a href="<?php echo Config::get('url'); ?>address.php" class="element<?='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == (Config::get('url') . 'address.php') ? ' active' : ''?>">
         <i class="lnr lnr-chart-bars"></i> 
         <span>Address Book</span>
     </a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href="<?php echo Config::get('url'); ?>product.php" class="element<?='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == (Config::get('url') . 'product.php') ? ' active' : ''?>">
        <i class="lnr lnr-cog"></i> 
        <span>Products</span>
    </a>
 </li>

 <li>
     <a href="<?php echo Config::get('url'); ?>bill.php" class="element<?='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == (Config::get('url') . 'bill.php') ? ' active' : ''?>">
        <i class="lnr lnr-alarm"></i> 
        <span>Invoice</span>
     </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```